# Google cardboard VR closing the whole application after pressing switching VR off button

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard, google-vr

Hi there Im using Unity 2022 and latest version of Google cardboard VR, Im trying to switch between VR and normal mode but when I press the close VR button after switching the view back to normal it closes the whole app, I searched in the scripts related to the VRController.cs and the functions it calls but I cant find anything regarding Application.Quit();

How can I switch the VR off without closing the application ?
This is the script :

```
void Start()
{
    _mainCamera = Camera.main;
    Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
    Screen.brightness = 1.0f;
 
}

void Update()
{
    
    if(_isVrModeEnabled && Api.IsCloseButtonPressed)
    {
        ExitVR();
    }
}
public void ToggleVR()
{
    if (_isVrModeEnabled)
    {
        ExitVR();
    }
    else
    {
        EnterVR();
    }
    // if (Api.HasNewDeviceParams())
    // {
    //     Api.ReloadDeviceParams();
    // }
}

private void EnterVR()
{
    StartCoroutine(StartXR());
    if (Api.HasNewDeviceParams())
    {
        Api.ReloadDeviceParams();
    }
}

private void ExitVR()
{
    StopXR();
}

private void StopXR()
{
    Debug.Log("Stopping XR...");
    XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.StopSubsystems();
    Debug.Log("XR stopped.");

    Debug.Log("Deinitializing XR...");
    XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.DeinitializeLoader();
    Debug.Log("XR deinitialized.");

    _mainCamera.ResetAspect();
    _mainCamera.fieldOfView = _defaultFieldOfView;
}

// Start is called before the first frame update
private IEnumerator StartXR()
{
    Debug.Log("Initializing XR...");
    yield return XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.InitializeLoader();

    if (XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.activeLoader == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Initializing XR Failed.");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("XR initialized.");

        Debug.Log("Starting XR...");
        XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.StartSubsystems();
        Debug.Log("XR started.");
    }
}

private bool _isVrModeEnabled
{
    get { return XRGeneralSettings.Instance.Manager.isInitializationComplete; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggest you make a Development Build, to check for possible errors while running the app. And add some Debug.Log lines to see if the code you think is running, or not.